# How do I repeat this JQuery Function/ Animation?

Tags: jquery

I have this code which I got from [Github](https://github.com/zemax/jquery-splitFlap) and at the moment what it does is that it calls the function once and then stops but I want it to repeat itself 3 times and within those 3 times want it to have a delay of like 10 seconds.

I tried using setInterval but it didn't work. When I try to insert setInterval into the code, the second time it tries to do the animation it doesn't work properly. So could you please help me out?

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pr2amqsp/)

HTML code:

```
<div class="resized-splitflap sixthAnimation">  London  </div>
<div class="resized-newyork sixthAnimation"> New York </div>
<div class="resized-dublin sixthAnimation">  Dublin  </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 (function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var ratio = 0.5;
        $('.resized-splitflap').splitFlap({
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        });

            $('.resized-newyork').splitFlap({
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        });
                    $('.resized-dublin').splitFlap({
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        });
        }, 1 * 1000);
  });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With onComplete event you can:

```
    var ratio = 0.3;
    $('.resized-splitflap').splitFlap({
        charWidth:  25 * ratio,
        charHeight: 50 * ratio,
        imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px',
        onComplete: function() {

           $('.resized-newyork').splitFlap({
              charWidth:  25 * ratio,
              charHeight: 50 * ratio,
              imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px',
              onComplete:function() {

                $('.resized-dublin').splitFlap({
                     charWidth:  25 * ratio,
                     charHeight: 50 * ratio,
                     imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
                });
               }
           });
        }
   });
```

It's a weird nested function code, but it works.

## Edit

As I tell you , it works. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pr2amqsp/1/

Comment: Could you give it to me in js fiddle please :)

Comment: I am on mobile now, I can't. Did you test it? I wish it works

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. so I dunno if I am doing anything wrong. But when you have time can you provide me the code in js fiddle? :)

Comment: Tomorrow I can. Did you see javascript console log? It throws an error?

Comment: nope no errors. and okay thanks! will be looking forward to your answer! :)

Comment: I edit my answer, you can see it works. You can copy and paste code and it must work. Please, accept as the correct answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I was looking for...I want it to play the animation at the same time so for london, new york and dublin all at the same time. But for 3 times...

Comment: I am making tests and this plugin hasn't a `destroy()` method. If I initialize the `splitFlap` object when it's initialize yet without a destroy, browser crashes with a script locking execution. I see for a method to destroy or remove the object and it will work. Are you attempting something?

Comment: I have been stuck on this for few days now and trying everything I can however saying this Jquery is not my expertise so yeh. But thanks for the help and hoping that you can help me out :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't help you so much. The only thing that I think it works without a destroy method, is remove elements and create them dinamically when animation ends. Maybe I try with a snippet and I share you